# How to create a KDE Desktop shortcut for firefox?

Tags: fedora, kde, firefox, desktop-shortcuts

I have installed new firefox on my Fedora 21 Linux "outside of a package manager" through the following webpage instructions:
[Install Firefox on Linux](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux)

However, it does not create a shortcut on my desktop and I would need some help doing it correctly. (The reason I did not install it from Apper software management is that my Fedora 21 is kind of outdated and it only has Firefox 42 version in its repository.)

Also I am receiving the following warnings:

```
(firefox:2387): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox:2387): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
Component returned failure code: 0x80570016 (NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.getService]Component returned failure code: 0x80570016 (NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.getService]
```

After running the command line:

```
~/firefox/firefox
```

it does run correctly and firefox 49 is launched with no issue.

Comment: You could open the terminal and create a link 'ln -s ~/firefox/firefox ~/Desktop.firefox'

Comment: I did that and now I do have files Desktop.firefox and firefox/firefox in the home directory but when I click on the remnent  firefox icon in the menu, it says: "Unable to run the command specified. The file or folder file:///usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop does not exist."